# Hibernate Single Table Inheritance with 2 @DiscriminatorColumn (1 is embedded) is not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Single `@DiscriminatorColumn` works fine. Column `product_type` gets filled with correct discriminator value:
[image: First @DiscriminatorCOlumn usage]

However, when I introduce 2 more classes that inherit Book, hence another `@DiscriminatorColumn`, none of the contracts are honored. Neither `product_type` gets populated (remains null) nor do `book_type`.

[image]

Comment: What type of table inheritance (single table, joined, table per class) are you attempting to use this in? JPA doesn't support this use case of multiple inheritance branches like this - it leaves it as undefined but states the discriminator column should be on the inheritance root, MyProduct in your case. "Book" should use the product_type column for inheritance as all book subclasses are a subclass of MyProduct, so there is no need to further differentiate them

Comment: I fixed the diagrams. I want to use 2 different discriminators for 2 different columns. 1st is of `product_type` and other is 'book_type'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having multiple disciminator columns on a single entity is not possible according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/DiscriminatorColumn.html)

> The strategy and the discriminator column are only specified in the
> root of an entity class hierarchy or subhierarchy in which a different
> inheritance strategy is applied.